# Filter array of objects by property using a list

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I'm trying to filter by a list of values:

```
     var idlist = [
    {
      id: '1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
    },
    {
      id: '6',
    },
  ]

  var values = ['1', '6', '3']
```

one way i've found to do this is to convert my list into an object and then filter using

```
   value.filter(k => 
     obj.find(v => v.id === k.id)
  )
```

However, I feel like that's an extra step I don't need. Is there a simpler solution?
The output i'm looking for is
new idlist

```
 [
    {
      id: '1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
    },

    {
      id: '6',
    },
  ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```js
idlist.filter(f => values.includes(f.id))
```

```js
var idlist = [{
    id: '1',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
  },
  {
    id: '6',
  },
]

var values = ['1', '6', '3']

console.log(idlist.filter(f => values.includes(f.id)))
```